# Issue with base64 encoding and decoding from java to c#

Tags: c#, java

I have converted image byte array to base64encoded string in Java using

```
Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(baos.toByteArray());
```

and I am able to decode it back to byte array ans save the image in file which is same as original file . But when I pass the base64 encoded string to the ASP .NET web service , and try to decode using

```
Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
```

I am unable to reproduce the same image . Please suggest  me the correct way to decode - an encoded base64 image in java- in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you use commons-codec from Apache as Java does not have a class `Base64` in the standard API.

You use the wrong method from the class `Base64` on the Java side. You have to use

```
Base64.encodeBase64(baos.toByteArray());
```

The method you're using is to create base64 in an URL safe manner and not the default base64 encoding.

See also the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history) for the differences.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I have changed the method to Base64.encodeBase64String(baos.toByteArray()); . Its working now :)

Comment: @sulthana If the solution works for you it is nice to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).